# How do I combine tables with null in mySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have tables

product

```
model   speed  type
1001    1      pc
1002    2      pc
1003    1      pc
2001    null   laptop
2002    null   laptop
```

Laptop

```
model   speed  screen
2001    1      12
2002    2      13
```

I want the table

```
model   speed  screen type
1001    1      null   pc
1002    2      null   pc
1003    1      null   pc
2001    1      12     laptop
2002    2      13     laptop
```

My ATTEMPT

```
SELECT
    product.model
FROM Laptop LEFT JOIN product
ON (product.model = laptop.model)
UNION
SELECT
    product.model
FROM Laptop RIGHT JOIN product
ON (product.model = laptop.model)
```

I would get "speed is ambiguous" errors. How to fix?

Comment: I don't see `speed` in the query.  Are you sure this query is the problem?

Comment: Because of the duplicates between Laptop and product, I think it expects me to choose between one of them while I want to combine them.

Comment: If you want to include `speed` in your `SELECT`, then you need to specify which `speed` do you want to get, `product.speed` or `laptop.speed`.

Comment: Looking for both. If I choose laptop.speed 1001 - 1003 speed's would be null or I choose product.speed same result but for laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT
    product.model, laptop.speed
FROM Laptop LEFT JOIN product
ON (product.model = laptop.model)
UNION
SELECT
    product.model, product.speed
FROM Laptop RIGHT JOIN product
ON (product.model = laptop.model)
```